# how to remove LAMP completely

Tags: uninstall, lamp, wordpress

I messed up by followed certain guideline to install LAMP for wordpress development and now i'm confused for what I have done.

So now i want to remove everything and start again.

Can u guys show me where can I learn to uninstall LAMP in ubuntu 16.04? Lots of tutorial teach to install but less about uninstall

BTW I'm still new to linux

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 php5 mysql-server-5.0 phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Hope this was helpful.
if not ping me sudo apt-get remove --purge phpmyadmin